# Fail2ban fails to start when setting an action

Tags: linux, centos, fail2ban

After installing fail2ban and modifying its configuration it fails to start whenever i set the action to anything... 
here is the error, but note that `$(action_mwl)s` can will be diferent for any action i set.

The OS is Centos 7, with firewalld.

```
   -- Unit fail2ban.service has begun starting up.
    מרץ 17 13:49:23 void fail2ban-client[28202]: ERROR  Error in action definition $(action_mwl)s
    מרץ 17 13:49:23 void fail2ban-client[28202]: ERROR  Errors in jail 'sshd'. Skipping...
    מרץ 17 13:49:23 void systemd[1]: fail2ban.service: control process exited, code=exited status=255
    מרץ 17 13:49:23 void systemd[1]: Failed to start Fail2Ban Service.
    -- Subject: Unit fail2ban.service has failed
    -- Defined-By: systemd
    -- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
    --
    -- Unit fail2ban.service has failed.
    --
    -- The result is failed.
    מרץ 17 13:49:23 void systemd[1]: Unit fail2ban.service entered failed state.
    מרץ 17 13:49:23 void systemd[1]: fail2ban.service failed.
    מרץ 17 13:49:23 void systemd[1]: fail2ban.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
    מרץ 17 13:49:23 void systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for fail2ban.service
    מרץ 17 13:49:23 void systemd[1]: Failed to start Fail2Ban Service.
    -- Subject: Unit fail2ban.service has failed
    -- Defined-By: systemd
    -- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
```

My settings are:

```
[DEFAULT]
# Ban hosts for 24 hours, if 3 attempts fail in 30 min:
bantime  = 86400
findtime  = 1800

# Email for banning notifications
destemail = myEmail@example.com
sendername = Fail2Ban
mta = sendmail

action = $(action_mwl)s

[sshd]
enabled = true
```

I hope i didn't do anything too silly, and thanks ahead!

Comment: Is `$(action_mwl)s` not getting substituted into the config file appropriately?

Comment: I didn't change anything, this is a separate file. (`jail.local`)